# Centos server keeps jumping to address instead of static assigned address

Tags: linux, networking, centos, static-ip

I have a headless Centos server that I've configured with a static IP address. I've disabled Network Manager, avahi-daemon etc. Whenever I restart the network it just jumps to 10.155.90.100 instead of the required 10.155.90.61 with no explanation:

Here is my ifcfg-eth0:

```
   # Intel Corporation 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)
    DEVICE=eth0
    BOOTPROTO=static
    ONBOOT=yes
    #HWADDR=00:50:56:b0:5a:57
    IPADDR=10.155.90.61
    NETMASK=255.255.255.0
    GATEWAY=10.155.90.1
    TYPE=Ethernet
    USERCTL=no
    IPV6INIT=no
    PEERDNS=yes
    NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

It seems to be running DHCP anyway. I cant seem to get a more detailed log than this in /var/log/messges:

```
Jul 11 12:50:33 NET[4767]: /sbin/dhclient-script : updated /etc/resolv.conf
Jul 11 12:50:34 kernel: 8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device eth0
Jul 11 12:50:34 kernel: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Jul 11 12:50:34 kernel: e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
Jul 11 12:50:34 kernel: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Jul 11 12:50:36 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x39edae98)
Jul 11 12:50:36 dhclient: DHCPACK from 10.155.50.20 (xid=0x39edae98)
Jul 11 12:50:36 NET[5157]: /sbin/dhclient-script : updated /etc/resolv.conf
Jul 11 12:50:36 dhclient: bound to 10.155.90.100 -- renewal in 255205 seconds.
```

How can I turn off DHCP and stop the server jumping for the wrong IP?

Comment: deinstall the service? dhclient

Comment: What other files do you have by way of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*`?  Anything that might be starting `dhclient` there?  Or perhaps something hand-hacked in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`?

Comment: @DennisNolte. That fixed it!

Comment: @blarg added an answer. however the other answers are worth reading aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

plain and simple solution: deinstall what you dont need :)

```
yum remove dhclient
```

Comment: Or just stop the service.

Comment: It will fix this problem but it's a bit "brute force". What if other interfaces need DHCP? I would investigate Nathan C's answer below about PEERDNS.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need `PEERDNS` since you're using a static IP. This is causing `dhclient` to run and update your `resolv.conf` file (as it's designed to do). In the process, it also requests an IP address when it requests the nameservers from DHCP.

Answer (score 2):

To assign a fixed IP address, use `none` as the value for `BOOTPROTO`.

From the "RHEL5 Deployment Guide", section ["Interface Configuration Files"](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html#s2-networkscripts-interfaces-eth0):

> `BOOTPROTO=protocol`
>
> where `protocol` is one of the following:
>
> - `none` — No boot-time protocol should be used.
> - `bootp` — The BOOTP protocol should be used.
> - `dhcp` — The DHCP protocol should be used.

Comment: I don't think that's right; I use `BOOTPROTO=static` very happily in all sorts of CentOS boxes, specifically both C5 and C6, with no problems.

Comment: Maybe he should have a look at the documentation i.e. `less /usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysconfig.txt` and search for `BOOTPROTO`. It says `BOOTPROTO=none|bootp|dhcp` on Scientific Linux 6.5.

Comment: It appears `none` or `static` is dependent on the OS. RHEL5 changed it, but from the research I've done (like [this wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS6)) CentOS still uses `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm a hack, but I like using the `system-config-network-tui` utility on RHEL/CentOS/RPM-based system for this, as it helps clean up any funky or hand-(mis)configured interface scripts.